# Peskin and Schroeder, Eq 2.52 with a spacelike interval.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics, quantum-field-theory

From the book "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by Peskin and Schroeder, in page 27, they give the following derivation:

We have the amplitude:

$$
D(x - y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int \text{d}^{3}p \frac{1}{2 E_{p}} \exp \left(-i p \cdot (x- y) \right)
$$

And if we consider the case where $x - y$ is spacelike: $x^{0} - y^{0} = 0$, $\vec{x} - \vec{y} = \vec{r}$, then the amplitude becomes:

$$
D(x - y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int \text{d}^{3}p \frac{1}{2 E_{p}} \exp \left(i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{r} \right) \tag{1}
$$

Changing to spherical coordinate, we get:

$$
= \frac{2 \pi}{(2\pi)^3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{d}p \frac{p^{2}}{2 E_{p}} \frac{\exp\left(ipr\right) - \exp\left(-ipr\right)}{i p r} \tag{2}
$$

This part is where I get lost. I don't know how they got from the exponential function, $\exp \left(i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{r} \right)$, to something of the form:

$$\frac{\sin(pr)}{pr}$$

My initial guess was to used identities with Bessel functions. Knowing that $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{r} = p r \cos\left(\alpha\right)$, for some $\alpha$, I tried with the identities mentioned in [NIST DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9#E1) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Composition_of_trigonometric_functions), but to be honest, I don't know how to continue.

If someone could give me a clue, I will appreciate. Thank you!.

Comment: Using $\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{r}=pr\cos(\theta)$ in spherical $p$ co-ords, you can do the integral over $\theta$ and $\phi$ directly , noting $d^3p\to p^2\sin(\theta)dp \ d\theta \ d\phi$), and $E(\mathbf{p})=E(p)$

Comment: @Sal You're right, now I feel like an idiot. I never thought of making a change of coordinates where the vector $\vec{r}$ is over the z-axis, making $\alpha$ and the polar angle the same. Thank you!.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple, and I feel dumb for not catch it before. Thank you @Sal.

We consider a changing of coordinates that make the vector $\vec{r}$ rest over the z-axis, with this the dot product becomes $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{r} = p r \cos(p_{\theta})$ where $p_{\theta}$ is the zenith angle of $\vec{p}$. Plugging this in (1), we get:

$$
D(x - y) = \frac{2 \pi}{(2\pi)^3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{d}p \frac{p^{2}}{2 E_{p}} \left[ \int_{0}^{\pi} \text{d}p_{\theta} \sin \left(p_{\theta}\right) \exp \left(i p r \cos \left(p_{\theta}\right) \right) \tag{3} \right]
$$

From here the integral is straightforward.

The reason why this works is because $\vec{r}$ is fixed, the integral (1) only depends on the magnitude of $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{r}$ and the relative position between both vectors, then the expression is invariant under a rotation, that give us the freedom to set $\vec{r}$ in wherever place we want. One solution would be to make the dependency of the projection angle only of one of the spherical angle (in the original expression, $\alpha$ depends on both) because the dependency of the azimuthal angle is more hard to work, then we chose the polar angle, which give us the integral from before.

Answer (score 1):

Peskin and Schroeder give an argument that this is essentially:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
D(x - y) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^{2}}\int^{\infty}_{m}\sqrt{E^{2}-m^{2}}\exp(-\mathrm{i}Et)\,\mathrm{d}E.
\end{equation}

If we just blindly compute this integral (or plug it into Mathematica), we get a modified Bessel function of the second kind:

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
D(x - y) = \frac{-\mathrm{i}}{4\pi^{2}t}K_{1}(\mathrm{i}mt).
\end{equation}

This is a bit handwavy, since we need $m\gt0$ and the imaginary part of time be negative --- i.e., $\mathrm{Im}(t)\lt0$. But let us soldier on, and see what happens.

Using the asymptotic expansion of $K_{\alpha}(z)$ as found in Abramowitz and Stegun [9.7.2](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_378.htm):

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
K_{\alpha}(z) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2z}} e^{-z} \left(1 + \frac{4 \alpha^2 - 1}{8z}+ \cdots \right).
\end{equation}

Taking the leading term, then plugging it into Eq (2), we get

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
D(x - y) \sim \frac{-\mathrm{i}}{4\pi^{2}t}
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\mathrm{i}mt}} e^{-\mathrm{i}mt} \left(1 + \frac{3}{8\mathrm{i}mt}+ \cdots \right).
\end{equation}

This requires a bit of cavalier calculation, though.

Comment: Yes, I got the same answer, but this is only valid for the timelike interval. The integral (1) is different when you consider a pure spatial interval, as the dependency of time-energy in the exponential banish and only survive the spatial-momentum part. Thank you for your answer!